# When does a meta proposal become "official policy"?

Tags: support

When does a proposal at meta become "official policy"? Especially in light of the moderators elections I would like to know which role moderators play in this process.

@AlexBecker comment, I mean "added to the faq, enforced by mods". Or maybe "enforced by the community". Closing PSQ questions is something that could be done without moderators. It seems like there are enough 3000+ users that want to close those questions. I guess that those users aren't closing those PSQ questions as it isn't "official" policy. Is this correct? How does something like that work at MSE?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "official policy"? Do you mean added to the faq, enforced by mods, stated by the SE devs, or what?

Comment: "How does something like that work at MSE ?" I'm tempted to say "poorly". I don't think there is an accepted standard, which I think is one of the major barriers to enforcement.

Comment: The problem with people just starting to close PSQ is that there are enough people who wouldn't mind, or even actively want them to be reopened. So you get a lot of close-reopen wars, in which case everyone loses. This is why prior discussions on meta are important.

Comment: Also the Q in PSQ stands for Question, so writing "PSQ questions" makes little sense.

Comment: @Asaf: I guess it makes as much sense as saying "ATM machine", which is

Comment: ...common.${}{}$

Comment: If the majority of users are indeed disgusted by the sort of  questions under consideration, they can downvote them into oblivion (=disappearance at the score of -4)  without causing any re-open wars. They don't need a policy to do this.

Comment: You need a PIN number to operate an ATM machine.

Comment: Nice, @GerryMyerson!